# Error HTML on Blogger: Erreur d'analyse XML, ligne 2269, colonne 2 : The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: html

Does anyone know what error appears here? I'll appreciate if you can let me know how to correct it.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to know what is written in line 2296, column 2 in the document (and most lines before that). Otherwise it is a bit hard to tell you what's wrong with it. Can you provide a link or post the part that appears to be malformed?

Comment: Thank you Torf, I managed at last to correct it yesterday. Thanks!